# Database code in controller to store data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

DB code issue

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

        $this->validate($request, [
            'Schedule Name' => 'required'
        ]);
        $schedule = new menu;
        $schedule->scheduleName = $request->input('Schedule Name');
        $schedule->days = $request->input('Days');
        $schedule->start_time = $request->input('Start Time');
        $schedule->end_time = $request->input('End Time');
        $schedule->save();

        return view('welcome')->with('success', 'Done');
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: `$schedule = new Menu;` class first latter should be capital

Comment: There shouldn't be space between input names

Comment: Brief your issue. Alway put model class name  start with capital word and do not put any space in input field name.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issue in code.

$schedule = new Menu; // Model name should be with capital

All input field should not contain space.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the following controller method:

```
use App\Menu;
public function store(Request $request)
{

        $this->validate($request, [
            'Schedule Name' => 'required'
        ]);
        $schedule = new Menu;   //use camel case Menu in you model and table likes menus.
        $schedule->scheduleName = $request->input('Schedule Name');
        $schedule->days = $request->input('Days');
        $schedule->start_time = $request->input('Start Time');
        $schedule->end_time = $request->input('End Time');
        $schedule->save();

        return view('welcome')->with('success', 'Done');
}
```